# Wait until UIElement is drawn (without updatelayout)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uielement

I have a function that takes around 5 seconds to complete if a button is clicked. If the button is clicked, I want to display some kind of notification to indicate that the buttonclick is being processed, something like

```
<Button Click="OnButtonClick" Content="Process Input" />

<Border x:Name="NotificationBorder" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
        Width="500" Height="100" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="Your input is being processed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

And in code-behind on the button click:

```
private void OnButtonClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 5,
            To = 0,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5),
        };

    // Making border visible in hopes that it's drawn before animation kicks in
    NotificationBorder.Opacity = 1;
    da.Completed += (o, args) => NotificationBorder.Opacity = 0;

    NotificationBorder.UpdateLayout(); //Doesn't do anything
    UpdateLayout(); // Doesn't do anything

    NotificationBorder.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, da);

    // Simulate calculationheavy functioncall
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Somehow `UpdateLayout()` isn't rendering fast enough, the notification is only displayed after the 5 seconds of `Thread.Sleep` are over.

`Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => NotificationBorder.Opacity = 1), DispatcherPriority.Render);` won't work either.

Additionally, I can't let `Thread.Sleep` run in a separate worker thread - In the real application, it needs to read data from Dispatcher-owned objects and (re)build parts of the UI.

Is there a way to make it visible before `Thread.Sleep()` is called?

Comment: Have you tried Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Thread.Sleep(5000)) ?

Comment: You aren't seeing the update because your simulation is sleeping the UI thread. You will see the same behaviour if your long running process is in the main thread too.

Comment: You will need to execute the long running function asynchronously, in a seperate thread. You may use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to perform this task.

Comment: And why are you animating the Opacity of the `NotificationBorder` from 5 to 0? Opacity is a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Clemens: So that the Opacity is visible and fades out only in the last 20% of the animation (I haven't bothered searching for a "better" alternative, if there is one?). Can the `BackgroundWorker` access Dispatcher-owned objects? I.e. resort the items from a datagrid?

Comment: You should have searched for the right way to do. There is a [BeginTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime.aspx) property. For the second question: yes, by means of the Dispatcher's Invoke method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is any long activity on main thread (UI thread) will lead freeze in UI, so you will not see any animation.

You need to do your calculations in a separate thread. I you need to access to Dispatcher-owned objects you can use uiObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Invoke. BackgroundWorker can help you the way to execute some long calculations and subscribe to the event Completed which will be fired by BackgroundWorker on the UI thread automatically.

If you are ok with UI freeze, change some property and other stuff re-schedule with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,...), like

NotificationBorder.Opacity = 1;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)(()=>Thread.Sleep(5000)));

Comment: I don't think the OP will really be okay with the UI freeze here, as even if the initial border gets displayed due to the priority change, the animation won't run while the UI thread is blocked.

Comment: Sure, thats why I wrote 'If you are ok with UI freeze'

Answer (score 1):

If you want the UI to update, you need to change your long-running operation to be asynchronous, which means properly decoupling the UI dependencies from whatever logic or perhaps IO-bound operations are taking all the time.  If you don't do this, none of the UI updates occurring in your long-running operation will actually be reflected in the UI until it's done, anyway.

If you're running with .NET 4.5, here is my preferred pattern for how to do this:

```
    public async Task DoComplexStuff()
    {
        //Grab values from UI objects that must be accessed on UI thread

        //Run some calculations in the background that don't depend on the UI
        var result = await Task.Run((Func<string>)DoComplexStuffInBackground);

        //Update UI based on results

        //Possibly do more stuff in the background, etc.
    }

    private string DoComplexStuffInBackground()
    {
        return "Stuff";
    }
```

This is somewhat 'backwards' from the older style BackgroundWorker approach, but I find it tends to result in cleaner logic.  Instead of writing your background code, with explicit Invokes for UI updates, you write your UI code around explicit background work calls via `Task.Run()`.  This also tends to lead to a natural separation between the UI-centric code and the underlying logic code, as you need to refactor your logic into methods that can be called in this way.  That's a good idea for long-term maintainability anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So you can dispatch both action (UI and your calculations) into the dispatcher and they will be executed in a line

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(do ui things);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(do your logic things);
```

But you'd better move your calculation into the background thread.